# Is there any alternative to @PreCreate and @PostCreate for saveOrUpdate in hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpa

We have a situation where an Entity cant expose a public setter for updating timestamp for createdOn property. It needs to be done within @PreCreate scope. But in Hibernate, this does not get called in case we are using saveOrUpdate

I have tried using SaveOrUpdateEventListner. It works but it creates two queries...first to insert and second to update those values.

Is there a way to avoid this ?

Comment: Should work IMHO.

Comment: @antonio whst should work ?saveorupdate ? Because it does not